# Kahler Einstein metric with minimal singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

> Let $X$ be a Kahler variety with snc divisor $D$ such that $K_X+D$ is
>   ample. then there is a Kahler metric $\omega_E$ such that
>   $Ric(\omega_E)=-\omega_E$ on $E=X\setminus D$, then
>   $h=\frac{1}{\omega_E^n}$, has not minimal singularity. But can we
>   construct a singular hermitian metric so that has minimal
>   singularities on pair $(X,D)$?

Note: We know from Demailly's theorem, every pseudoeffective line bundles on compact complex manifolds admit minimal singular metrics, but the Demailly's definition and Tsuji's definition are slightly different for minimal singularities. Also I am looking for singular hermitian metric which constructed from KE metric.

> What about when $-(K_X+D)$ is ample? can we construct a singular
>   hermitian metric so that is Analytical Zariski Decomposition with
>   minimal singularities when we have log K-stability condition on pair
>   $(X,D)$?

Comment: the answer of first question is yes due to Hajime Tsuji